# Compiler on Linux for XScale pxa255

Tags: linux, compilation, xscale

Anyone does know how to compile a C source code for XScale PXA255 on Linux?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Xscale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XScale) seems to be some ARM (v5) variant. And the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (Gnu Compiler Collection) suite can target ARM.

Did you consider using a GCC cross-compiler (hosted on a Linux/AMD64 desktop, and targetting your ARM)?

You could compile from source GCC. Don't forget to follow the [GCC installation guidelines](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/). Be careful to follow them (there are also companies selling that service).

You also need a (cross-) assembler and linker. They are provided by [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and you can compile it in a cross- way (targetting your system).

The target operating system also matters.